# How to skip duplicate value from list comprehension using built in only methods

Tags: python

Using a list comprehension

```
myList=[-2,-1,0,1,2,3,1,2,3]
result=[each for each in myList if each>0]
```

Results to:

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

How to avoid the duplicated values in returned list?

Comment: Do you care about order?

Comment: Here you go: `[other.append(x) for x in myList if x > 0 and x not in other]`

Comment: Looks like you need to pre-declare `other` as a list to make it work. Thanks!